# Jquery .each() renders [object HTMLUListElement] instead of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on trying to dynamically create "ul" elements **after** "h1" elements (or any element really).  In doing so, I've chose to use `$('h1').each()` to iterate over all `<h1>` elements, then use `el.after("some html")` to add to DOM.  However, rather than displaying the HTML `<ul>` output, it's just displaying `[object HTMLUListElement]`.
As a test, I decided to try `$('h2').after("some html")` without any iteration.  For this test, it properly renders the `<ul>` element under every `<h2>` header.
I'm looking for help to get the `$.each()` method to correctly display the `<ul>` element.

This is a much more watered down version of what I'm trying to accomplish.  The main goal of using the `$.each()` versus not using is because I have to dynamically create the UL and child LI elements from other variables.  I kept out the unnecessary complexity for the purposes of this question since I was able to reproduce the problem without all the extra noise.

```js
test = "<ul><li>UL list item 1</li><li>UL list item 2</li></ul>";
test_html = $.parseHTML(test);
$('h1').each(function(i,el){
  el.after(test_html);
});

$('h2').after(test_html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Test 1</h1>
  <h1>Test 1 Again</h1>

  <h2>Test 2</h2>
  <h2>Test2 Again</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `el` is a dom node, therefore `.after` is the native `childNode.after` method which expects a string or a dom node. `test_html` is an array, it is therefore converted to a string, thus resulting in what you see. If you converted `el` to a jquery collection or used the first item in the test_html array, it would work.

Comment: @KevinB I tried this `test_html = $.parseHTML(test)[0];`, and the `ul` is being appended after the 2nd `h1`, but not the first `h1`.

Comment: @Rojo OP wants to see the actual html rendered instead of [object HTMLUListElement]

Comment: @Spencer Yes, because .after doesn't clone. In that scenario you're literally appending the same dom node twice, it gets appended to the first, and then moved to the second.

Comment: @KevinB..thanks for the input.  When you say "el is a dom node", I'm assuming that it take on each "h1" dom node as it iterates through the collection returned by $('h1').each().  Is this correct ?  For your statement "If you converted e1 to a jquery collection....it would work" --- isn't that what the $('h2').after(test_html) is doing ?  For my purposes, i have to be able to create unique "ul" after each H1 (or some other element).  Are you saying to convert "el" to a collection of size = 1, then use "after" on that collection ?  If so, how do you do this ?  Thanks!

Comment: *"isn't that what the $('h2').after(test_html) is doing"* kinda sorta. Because `.after` is a jquery method in that case, and jQuery  methods tend to handle arrays of dom elements gracefully, and clones when appending to multiple, it will work as expected.

Comment: And, for your former question, yes, `el` in each iteration will be an h1 dom node (not a jquery collection.) but converting it to a jquery collection still wouldn't result in cloning the element you are appending, therefore it still wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys...looks like @King11 recommendation is what i needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

JSfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/grusjoyb/

I took out the parameters in your function and added `$(this)` instead. And just used the html string instead of the `.parseHtml` object.

So I ended up changing your `.each` function from

`$('h1').each(function(i,el){
  el.after(test_html);
});`

to

`$('h1').each(function(){
  $(this).after(test);
});`

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: this is exactly what i've been wanting.  Going to test it now...Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help